# UIImage to Button Method - pointer incompatibility error

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` called `myImage` which I would like to show when this is called:

```
JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc] 
  initWithImageInfo:
               mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
    backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundStyle_ScaledDimmedBlurred];
```

I assume `myImage` would need to go after `initWithImageInfo:`, right?  How do I do this?

I tried `initWithImageInfo:myImage` but this does not work.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myImage = [self getMyImageWithSize:(CGSizeMake)(100,100)];

    [self.imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bigButtonTapped:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
}

- (void)bigButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    // Create image info
    JTSImageInfo *imageInfo = [[JTSImageInfo alloc] init];
    imageInfo.image = [self.imageButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageInfo.referenceRect = self.imageButton.frame;
    imageInfo.referenceView = self.imageButton.superview;

    // Setup view controller
    JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc]
      initWithImageInfo:??????
                   mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
        backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundStyle_ScaledDimmedBlurred];

    // Present the view controller.
    [imageViewer showFromViewController:self transition:JTSImageViewControllerTransition_FromOriginalPosition];
}
```

I apologise if this is a stupid question but I've tried Googling for this issue and I can't seem to find anything relatable.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to set `imageInfo.image` to `myImage` and pass `imageInfo` to `initWithImageInfo:`.  The exact error message would help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at his sample app is very useful:

https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController/blob/a02ee23381bed69c995378fd4db400717ebf3fb1/Sample%20App/JTSImageVC/JTSImageVC/JTSViewController.m#L33-L45